# Sliding Tab Layout in iOS app developed in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tabs, sliding

I am developing an iOS app in Swift with the latest Xcode - Xcode 7 and would like to implement the "Sliding tab layout" feature available for Android apps.

I have seen some iOS apps as well which have Sliding Tab Layout.

How can I create a sliding tab layout in my iOS app?

Comment: Do you mean sliding menu or view pager but for iOS ? @bably

Comment: @Aaoli, I am looking for View Pager with Sliding tabs. I just found this link - https://github.com/lucoceano/Pager . Let me try and see if I can customise it. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Alright , there exist library called `PagingMenuController` on github helps you to go throw this and build what you want by this link : https://github.com/kitasuke/PagingMenuController. Or you may use the library you have found for that. as i said just download their project and see how it works, Then import it into your project.

You may download their library which is written by Swift and support Swift 2 and `IOS8+`.

**Note:** Try follow user experience and what i mean here IOS is different than android, i suggest you build `UITabbar` instead of this. as example : `WhatsApp` on android uses view pager but on iPhone uses `UITabbar`.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried and this library PagingMenuController is working as per my requirements.